# Updating object's property value behaves like a reference to another object's property value

Tags: javascript

Basically the code says everything. I have a variable `x` with a `css` property. I'm saving all the `css` of `x` into `y`, and then I change the value of the `y`'s property. This change also affects `x`, why? How to make it to only pass the value so that `x` stays unchanged?

```
var x = {};
x.css = {height: 100, width: 100};

var y = {};
y.css = x.css;
y.css.height = 200;

console.log(x.css.height); //equals to 200 while it should be 100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript assignment is done by reference and hence your `x.css` is also modified when you modify `y.css` . You can rather assign `y.css` using [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
var x = {};
x.css = {height: 100, width: 100};

var y = {};
y.css = Object.assign({}, x.css);
y.css.height = 200;

console.log(x.css.height);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating an object and then pointing two different variables at the same object. The most simplest explanation would be that you're are just giving variable x another name/variable accessor. Look at the below example to see how to overcome this, or you can create a copy of the object.

Solution 1: Use this trick to clone an object.

```js
var x = {};
x.css = {height: 100, width: 100};

var y = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x));
y.css.height = 200;

console.log('Y Height:', y.css.height);
console.log('X Height:', x.css.height);
```

Solution 2: Create a new instance that has it's own local properties

```js
var elementInstance = function() {
  return {
    css: {
      height: 100,
      width: 100
    }
  }
}

var x = new elementInstance();
var y = new elementInstance();

y.css.height = 200;

console.log(x, y); // They should be different instances
```